# wp_list_pages - displaying pages from a specific WordPress site (network)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a child theme that is applied to all of my network sites and I am trying to figure out a way to list Pages from the main site and display it on all sites. It seems it would be in wp_list_pages but there are no parameters to specify site with this function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research I ended up changing some variables with the $wpdb class

```
global $wpdb;
$old_blogid = $wpdb->blogid;
$wpdb->set_blog_id('1');
wp_list_pages( 'show_home=1&title_li=&depth=2' );
$wpdb->set_blog_id($old_blogid);
```

Blog ID (1) is the main site blog ID. the $wpdb class is located in wp-includes/wp-db.php for more function and properties references.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution for this is to use the `switch_to_blog` function. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog